# Why jQuery.noConflict() has no effect in this script?

Tags: jquery, slider, gallery

```
// Copyright 2010 htmldrive.net Inc.
/**
 * @projectHomepage: http://www.htmldrive.net/go/to/desSlideshow
 * @projectDescription: Stylish featured image slideshow jQuery plugin.
 * @author htmldrive.net
 * More script and css style : htmldrive.net
 * @version 1.0
 * @license http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 */
(function(a){
    a.fn.desSlideshow=function(p){
        var p=p||{};

        var autoplay=p&&p.autoplay?p.autoplay:"enable";
        var slideshow_width=p&&p.slideshow_width?p.slideshow_width:"600";
        var slideshow_height=p&&p.slideshow_height?p.slideshow_height:"250";
        var thumbnail_width=p&&p.thumbnail_width?p.thumbnail_width:"200";
        var time_Interval = p&&p.time_Interval?p.time_Interval:"4000";
        var directory=p&&p.directory?p.directory:"images";
        slideshow_height = parseInt(slideshow_height);
        slideshow_width = parseInt(slideshow_width);
        time_Interval = parseInt(time_Interval);
        var g=a(this);
        var current = -1;
        var y=g.children(".switchBigPic").children("div").length;
        var v;
        var w;
        if(y==0){
            g.append("Require content");
            return null
        }
        init();
        if(autoplay == "enable"){
            g.find(".switchBigPic").css("display","block");
            g.find(".nav").css("display","block");
            g.css("background","none");
            play();
        }else{
            g.find(".switchBigPic").css("display","block");
            g.find(".nav").css("display","block");
            g.css("background","none");
            current = 0;
            showpic();
        }
        g.find(".nav").children("li").hover(
            function(){
                var index = g.find(".nav").children("li").index($(this));
                if(index != current){
                    current = index;
                    showpic();
                }
            },
            function(){

            }
        );
        g.hover(
            function(){

            },
            function(){
                if(autoplay == "enable"){
                    v=setTimeout(play,time_Interval);
                }
            }
        );
        function init(){
            g.css("width",slideshow_width+"px").css("height",slideshow_height+"px").css("position","relative").css("font-family","Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif").css("border-top","1px solid #CCCCCC").css("overflow","hidden");
            g.find("a").css("color","#000");
            g.find("img").css("border","none");
            g.find("ul").css("margin","0px").css("padding","0px");
            g.find("li").css("margin","0px").css("padding","0px").css("list-style","none");
            g.find(".switchBigPic").css("position","relative");
            g.find(".switchBigPic").children("div").css("position","absolute").css("overflow","hidden");
            g.find(".switchBigPic").children("div").children("p").css("position","absolute").css("padding","5px").css("margin","0px").css("bottom","0px").css("opacity","0.6").css("background-color","#000").css("color","#FFF").css("font-size","12px").css("width","100%");
            g.find(".nav").css("width",thumbnail_width+"px").css("height",slideshow_height+"px").css("position","absolute").css("right","0px");
            g.find(".nav").children("li").css("height","49px").css("background-image","url("+directory+"flashtext-bg.jpg)").css("line-height","49px").css("border-bottom","1px solid #CCCCCC").css("border-right","1px solid #CCCCCC");
            g.find(".nav").children("li").children("a").css("text-decoration","none").css("height","49px").css("display","block").css("padding-left","25px").css("font-size","14px");
            g.find(".nav").children("li").css("margin-left","0px");
            g.find(".switchBigPic").children("div").hide();
        }
        function showpic(){
            clearTimeout(v);
            g.find(".nav").children("li").css("background-image","url("+directory+"flashtext-bg.jpg)").css("border-bottom","1px solid #CCCCCC");
            g.find(".nav").children("li").eq(current).css("background-image","url("+directory+"flash-on.gif)").css("border-bottom","none");
            g.find(".switchBigPic").children("div").fadeOut();
            g.find(".switchBigPic").children("div").eq(current).fadeIn();
            g.find(".nav").children("li").eq(current).animate({marginLeft: '-35px'}, "fast");
            g.find(".nav").children("li").eq(w).animate({marginLeft: '0px'}, "fast");
            w = current;

        }
        function play(){
            current++;
            if(current>=y){
                current=0
            }
            showpic();
            v=setTimeout(play,time_Interval);
        }
    }
})(jQuery);

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var $jl = jQuery.noConflict(); 
    $jl(function() {
        $jl("#desSlideshow1").desSlideshow({
            autoplay: 'enable',//option:enable,disable
            slideshow_width: '800',//slideshow window width
            slideshow_height: '249',//slideshow window height
            thumbnail_width: '200',//thumbnail width
            time_Interval: '4000',//Milliseconds
            directory: 'images/'// flash-on.gif and flashtext-bg.jpg directory
        });
        $jl("#desSlideshow2").desSlideshow({
            autoplay: 'disable',//option:enable,disable
            slideshow_width: '600',//slideshow window width
            slideshow_height: '249',//slideshow window height
            thumbnail_width: '120',//thumbnail width
            time_Interval: '4000',//Milliseconds
            directory: 'images/'// flash-on.gif and flashtext-bg.jpg directory
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hi, I saw a new jQuery slider gallery in the web today, and downloaded it to study.
There is just one JS file and a few `<script>` blocks in the body. When I change `$` to `jQuery.noConflict()`, it failed to work. Why?

Comment: Please paste a code example and do not force users to visit external links.

Comment: OK, I have copied all the js code for the hyperlink is not allow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` isn't to be replaced by `jQuery.noConflict()`, you should replace it with *only* `jQuery`, which `$` is usually an alias for (until [`.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) is called, setting it back to what it was before jQuery was loaded).

Alternatively just wrap your code to use `$`, like this:

```
(function($) {
  //code
})(jQuery)
```

Or for a `document.ready` call, a shortcut:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  //run stuff on ready
});
```

Comment: (function($) { 
    `$(function() {
        $("#desSlideshow1").desSlideshow({
            autoplay: 'enable',//option:enable,disable
            slideshow_width: '600',//slideshow window width
            slideshow_height: '250',//slideshow window height
            thumbnail_width: '200',//thumbnail width
            time_Interval: '4000',//Milliseconds
            directory: 'image/'// flash-on.gif and flashtext-bg.jpg directory
        });
    });
 })(jQuery) 
</script>`

Comment: I tyied to add a '(function($) { 
  //code 
})(jQuery)' out side, but not work.

Comment: @yuli - "not work" isn't a helpful description, *what* doesn't work? You should be seeing an error in your console, what is it?

Comment: the nav menu is not work, just work for the automatic slider show

Comment: @Nick Craver - NO,at least in IE8, the bottom left has no error hint.

Comment: it is a small exclamation point with yellow triangle. But when I run the code, there is no error hint, and the nav menu has no effect.

Comment: @yuli - have you tried it in another browser? IE is the worst to debug in.